# swf files not working in node webkit

Tags: node-webkit

i am building an desktop app using nodewebkit, html5 .
App consists of few swf animations embed to it.

Problem is node webkit is not supporting swf file.

How to make swf file work on node webkit

Answer (score 0):

Did you add

```
 "webkit": {
"plugin": true
```

} 
to your package.json.

You need to have flash installed on the computer.